# Why do chained get(), post() and put() methods not require the path argument?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm learning express from various tutorials and have an app working locally, but I'd like to better understand what each part of the code does.

I'm a bit stumped with the example in the `app.route()` section here:

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

```
app.route('/book')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Get a random book')
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Add a book')
  })
  .put(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Update the book')
  })
```

I can see that `app` is equal to `express()`, which is a top level function documented [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express).

And I can see that the `.get()`, `post()` and `put()` methods are chained to the `route()` method, which is documented [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.route).

Where I get confused is that the docs state that the arguments for the `.get()`, `post()` and `put()` methods are in this format:

```
app.get(path, callback [, callback ...])
app.post(path, callback [, callback ...])
app.put(path, callback [, callback ...])
```

Why do the chained `.get()`, `post()` and `put()` methods not require the `path` argument, and instead have a singular function as an argument that returns values from the [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) (aka `req`) and [Response](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) (aka `res`) object parameters?

I'm obviously missing something simple, so pointers to documentation that could help me better understand the distinctions between these methods when called straight from `app`, eg `app.get()`, and from `route()`, eg `app.route('/book').get()` would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**  Basically, I'd like to know if there is documentation that defines the required argument format for the `.get()`, `post()` and `put()` methods when called from the route object returned from calling `app.route("/book")`, because it does not seem to be what is documented, ie `path, callback [, callback ...]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app.route()**

As per the docs, the `app.route` method:

> Returns an instance of a single route, which you can then use to handle HTTP verbs with optional middleware. Use app.route() to avoid duplicate route names (and thus typo errors).

It means, `app.route()` takes only the path and returns the `route object`. Which will have all http verb methods to handle middlewares against one path, `get`, `post`, `delete`, `post`, `put`, `patch` etc.

**Why?**

To simply have routes which have same path but different HTTP requests. Like:

```
app.route('/books')
  .get() // To get the list of objects
  .post() // To save a new book.
```

**Individual HTTP methods**

On the other hand, express provides individual methods on `app` for handling HTTP requests. Like `app.get()`, `app.post()`, `app.delete()`.

> As per docs for post route: HTTP POST requests to the specified path with the specified callback functions.

**Why?**

For the cases where you don't have one path for multiple HTTP requests. Let's say:

```
app.delete('/books/:bookId/comments/:commentId', function(){});
```

The above route is a kind of single route and only used for deleting a specific comment on book.

I hope I was able to clear the difference.

> Reference Link for the docs: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route

**Edit:**

As no proper Docs are available listing methods provided by route object: 
For more information adding github's link to the express router.

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js

Here see the below code of express's router which adds handler on all methods.

```
methods.forEach(function(method){
  Route.prototype[method] = function(){
    var handles = flatten(slice.call(arguments));

    for (var i = 0; i < handles.length; i++) {
      var handle = handles[i];

      if (typeof handle !== 'function') {
        var type = toString.call(handle);
        var msg = 'Route.' + method + '() requires a callback function but got a ' + type
        throw new Error(msg);
      }

      debug('%s %o', method, this.path)

      var layer = Layer('/', {}, handle);
      layer.method = method;

      this.methods[method] = true;
      this.stack.push(layer);
    }

    return this;
  };
});
```

In this file at top, it has:

`var methods = require('methods');`

> methods: https://github.com/jshttp/methods

Thus, the required parameters for the chained methods is `unlimited functions` as request `handlers/middlewares`.

Comment: Is there documentation that defines what methods are available from the `route object`, and the required format of their arguments?   The documentation for `app.get()` does not seem to apply to `app.route("/book").get()` - the former requires `path, callback [, callback ...]` as arguments for `get()`, whilst the latter just has a single argument for `get()`, a function.  This is why I am asking the question `Why do the chained .get(), post() and put() methods not require the path argument`?

Comment: Hey I have updated my answer and added reference link to it. The thing is there is no API reference in the docs that clearly lists the methods on router object. But as per the docs. route object will have all HTTP verb methods.

Comment: It will have all `get`,`post`, `delete`, `post`, `put`, `patch` etc.

Comment: I have added more references to my answer from github code of express

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know the required *argument* format for chained `get()`, `post()` and `put()` methods.  I am looking at code that contains 2 functions as arguments in a chained `get()` method, eg `app.route("/book").get(loginRequired, getBook)`, and I have no way of knowing how this can be valid.

Comment: `var handles = flatten(slice.call(arguments));` means you can pass more than one methods to it. 

The arguments to the chained HTTP methods is only `handlers/functions`.

Comment: So the required argument format for these methods is therefore "unlimited functions" that all have the `req` and `res` objects available for them to use as parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170666/discussion-between-farhan-tahir-and-user1063287).

Answer (score 2):

The point of chained method is that they have same path.

So you can write this:

```
app.route('/book')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Get a random book')
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Add a book')
  })
  .put(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Update the book')
  })
```

instead of

```
  app.get('/book', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Get a random book')
  });
  app.post('/book', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Add a book')
  });
  app.put('/book', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Update the book')
  });
```

Which means that if you i.e. change the endpoint it is changed for all methods, you cannot write typo in one method...